# Notify checkbox is invisible

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When creating a new question, every time the label completion list pop up (during typing of tags), it causes the "Notify me of..." checkbox to become invisible, only after moving the mouse over it, it reappears.

I'm using Firefox 3 on Ubuntu.

Moreover, I tried taking a snapshot, but once I press Print Screen, it reappears...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: screenshot would be helpful

Comment: will, once it reoccurres

Comment: Do you have a digital camera on you perhaps?

Comment: @random: You are suggesting a *real* screen shot?

Comment: Yes, yes indeed.

Comment: There's nothing interesting to see though, just imagine the checkbox isn't there, but the rest is.

Comment: So the checkbox is a lie?

Comment: @abyx, please ensure that you can see the wood table underneath the screenshot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a font issue?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/login-page-layout-broken-ubuntu-ff-3

We have a lot of font issues with Ubuntu because the default fonts are *incredibly* wide, to the point that they break layout.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related, because it doesn't always happen, and the checkbox is not overlapping anything (the page layout seems fine).

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.